# Use a unique varchar as reference to a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, uuid

Warning: possible duplicate

Hi,

I have the following table

```sql
CREATE TABLE names (
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Now, `uuid` basically says, use a unique `VARCHAR(10)` as an index. The question that I have is: can't I just use `name` as an `id`, since it's unique anyway and takes up the same amount of space or would this have negative impact on foreign keys?

I'm not new to SQL, I've just never came across this conflict and now I'm wondering if I've been using some concepts wrong the whole time.

Comment: A numerical PK costs less space. A (var)char key can take more space, which is duplicated if other tables need it as a FK.

Comment: Thanks. I considered a numerical PK but I didn't want to go with incremental since it would indicate a certain "registration order", which shouldn't be visible from the ID itself.

Comment: You could use a larger bump value for the sequence, e.g. a rather large prime number if you want to obfuscate the serials.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this topic. Could you post a link?

Comment: I don't know if you can *massage*  `uuid`s. You can influence sequences and `IDENTITY`s. BTW: if UUID's are too predictable for you: don't use them.

Comment: Well, the size of  `name` is shorter than the 16 bytes a UUID occupies, so I don't really see a problem in removing the ID column completely. But the real question is: are you 100% sure that you will never, under any circumstance, ever change the `name`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name IIRC the uuids occupy 8 bytes(64 bits). [the difference is marginal]

Comment: @wildplasser: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) "*This identifier is a 128-bit quantity*" 128 bit = 16 bytes. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=29501b8e44c048bc58d79b5991633c92

Comment: Ok. I stand corrected.

Comment: OTOH: 128bits might be enough to enumerate every atom on earth...

Comment: @wildplasser yes, it will never change. It should actually represent a location. Those names rarely change.

Comment: Bit *if* the names change, every FK that refers to them would be affected.

Comment: @wildplasser well, as far as I know, the database won't have any ukraine city names ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Albert: you wrote: "yes, it will _never_ change. It should actually represent a location. Those names _rarely_ change."  - you are somehow contradicting yourself  ;) if it **never** changes, then it can not "rarely change". If there is event the _slightest_ possibility that the name changes, it's not really fit to be a primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I suppose you're right, thanks. I also only realise now that there are possibilities that some locations share the same `name`.

Comment: For names, there are also spelling errors, capitalisation, whitespace,encoding/charset , ...

Comment: @wildplasser sometimes, tuesdays are dressed like mondays *facepalm*